# Describe the exit codes in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, runtime-error, exit, exit-code

**Any idea about how many exit codes occur in Node.js?**

example:

Unused (reserved by Bash for builtin misuse)

Comment: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/errors.html#errors_node_js_error_codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Exit codes in Node.js are a specific group of codes that finish off
>   processes, which can include global objects as well. Some of the exit
>   codes in Node.js are:

- Internal JavaScript Evaluation Failure
- Fatal Error
- Internal Exception
- handler Run-time failure
- Unused
- Uncaught fatal exception